# Allowing unpermitted group to access share - Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, permissions, network-share, server-message-block

I've been a Linux sysadmin and am new to Windows so I apologize for the n00b question.  I have two groups lets call them "Students" and "Professors".  Students are very restricted, however professors have access to some unique things.  One of them is a P:\ drive.  The drive is mapped as follows:

```
\\Server\Public -> P:\
```

All Professors have full read\write access to this.  It is designed for them to share files with each other.  Students do not have access to \\Server\ or \\Server\Public but I have a professor who wants to share files with some students.

The only workaround I came up with so far (which leaves everything as far as permissions\shares go as they are) is to create a "Shared" folder in his local profile and share it with **EVERYONE**, and give **EVERYONE** read-only access.  Students can access it by going to "\\COMPUTER_NAME\Users\USER_NAME\Shared" (and that's all they can see).

The problem is the professor has to copy all the files to his local profile from the P drive.  It's not too big of a deal but I want a more elegant solution.  I tried creating a symlink in "Shared" as follows:

```
\\COMPUTER_NAME\Users\USER_NAME\Shared\linked_dir <-> \\Server\Public
```

but students still were unable to access it (I'm sure it is designed like that on purpose).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why are the students on the same AD Domain as the staff?

Comment: That's just how it came.  I work here, I didn't make it!  They are separated and have different groups and GPOs.  Why does it matter if they are in the same domain?

Comment: Most academic environments are better off putting students on their own AD domain and preferably own network entirely.  This helps to prevent security issues and problems with staff being able to do their jobs properly.

Answer (score 5):

If a user has rights to a sub-directory on a share, I believe it is possible to directly map to it.

```
net use m: \\server\public\jprof\cs101\files
```

You can't map M: (for example) directly to the share and navigate down, that's what messes some people up. To do that you'll have to get funky with permissions, and that's a lot of work.

Comment: I tried that and since students do not have access to \\server\Public that seems to mean they don't have to access to \\server\Public\shared_dir even when I gave EVERYONE full control

Comment: You have to set the SHARE level permissions for PUBLIC to "EVERYONE - FULL CONTROL" as well.

Comment: There is no ability to change them.  Properties on a standard (local) folder gives me the the sharing tab, but I do not have that tab on \\Server\Public\test_folder

Comment: Got it.  I can share E:\Public\test_folder (\\Server\Public maps to E:\Public on the server) by setting this as an Admin but this creates \\Server\test_folder.  This is ugly.  I want them to go to \\Server\Public\test_folder even though they can't go to \\Server\Public

Comment: You have to set the permissions on the PUBLIC share, then give them access to whatever that subfolder (files) is.  Then they can map directly to that subfolder (as in sysadmin's answer).  Assuming bypass traverse checking is enabled (by default it is), it will work fine.

Comment: The problem is they should not be able to even view \\Server\Public (or any subdirs) besides \\Server\Public\folder_to_share.  \\Server\Public is mainly for professors.  This is just a one-off case.

Comment: I understand that...you aren't following because you are new to how Windows works.  Share permissions for most of us are set as "EVERYONE - FULL CONTROL" and then you lock it all down via NTFS permissions.  Don't give them access to the PUBLIC folders NTFS permissions...just that one folder.  When they try and access \\server\PUBLIC it will fail.  Access to \\server\public\folder\files directly will be allowed.

Comment: Think of SHARE permissions as a rights mask: specified users/groups will never have more than these permissions no matter what the filesystem permissions say. If someone has Full Control on a folder, but the Share permissions are set to read-only, they'll only get read-only rights to that folder.